# Can I use PhoneGap to embed ASP.Net website to make Android App?

Tags: cordova, product

I am using .Net MVC 4 with JQuery Mobile to make a website that can both fit desktop browser and mobile experience.
However, I am also thinking of packing my website code into PhoneGap to make an Android app. is it possible? I doubt it since Eclipse does not have the compliler of .net.

I found the following chart, which indicates C# is not supported.
http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/

Let me know how I can plan for this kind of product and reuseable part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand that .NET is a Server Side Programming Language, so you cannot really put it into a client App. What you can do is Create a Service Layer out of your .NET Application and separate the front end from it which you have created using jQuery Mobile.

Then you can package the jQuery Mobile website using PhoneGap. Just use the online version of phonegap http://build.phonegap.com to upload your code in zip file and get the Android package.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Does that mean I cannot benefit from Razor to put cshtml page into PhoneGap project?

Answer (score 1):

If your .net code can output some-type of data (like xml or json) you could ingest that using Javascript within the app. But no, you cant run your .net application natively in a phonegap app.

Generally I have found that .Net requires custom postback's and misses with the page (by adding session state).

If this helped, please upvote.

Answer (score 1):

My vision on this is totally different.

I would build an Asp.net site and create a phone gap app with a browser control in it. Effectively this app will work just as a book mark to the site.

Also since phone gap have access to OS, it can post required info to server

Answer (score 0):

Just call your asp.net app url and use InAppBrowser with phonegap/cordova. Or webview in android native.